# What happens when I call finish() on an Activity that is already destroyed?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-volley, android-lifecycle

I'm realizing while reviewing some of my existing Activity code that some of the Volley async network response handlers call `finish()` to return to the caller (who typically start my Activity via `startActivityForResult`). Something like this:

```
private Response.Listener<MyResponse> mResponseListener = new Response.Listener<MyResponse>(){
    @Override public void onResponse(MyResponse myResponse) {

        // I could get here *after* rotation was initiated

        // do stuff

        finish();
    };
}
```

After some recent investigation into a bug, I realized my code does not handle the rotation case properly -- I have cases where a network response handler could, in theory, be called in between activity instance A1's destruction and activity instance A2's creation when the device is rotated. What effect does calling `finish()` after A1's `onDestroy` is called have? Is the fact that "we're done" lost? Does A2 get created and stick around as though `finish` were never called?

Comment: What are the symptoms of the bug ? Does your app crash ? If so, it would be nice to see some log

Comment: @inmyth I actually haven't seen any issues; this is from source analysis/code review from fixing a different bug (which was caused by the symptoms explained here: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html.)

Answer (score 3):

> What effect does calling finish() after A1's onDestroy is called have?

I'm not sure, but to me it seems like it should finish the activity and remove it from the task's back stack.

I think the root of your problem lies elsewhere, though - **Activities and Fragments really aren't the proper place to be handling network or other asynchronous operations.** You should treat Activities and Fragments more like dumb Views in terms of an MVC or MVP design - they should accept some data from a controller and render their Views accordingly.

Hence, the proper place for making async requests would be something like a plain Java class with an instance which is kept in the `Application` context, rather than in any `Activity` context. This way, the object that is performing your async operation is not bound to the fickle Activity/Fragment lifecycle.

For example, I like using `EventBus` with its cross-thread sticky events to communicate between the object making the request and the Activity that has to display the result, subscribing an event listener in the Activity's `onResume` callback and unsubscribing in `onPause`.

An article that helped me tremendously in learning to think of Activities and Fragments was [this one by Matt Swanson](http://www.mdswanson.com/blog/2014/04/07/durable-android-rest-clients.html).

Comment: I'm coming to the same realization as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what happens after onDestroy is that the Activity reaches the end of its lifecycle and is soon garbage collected.

I can think of two solutions for your case

1. Cancel all Volley Requests in onDestroy. You can use RequestQueue#cancelAll which cancels all requests given a specific tag. This tag is attached when instantiating a Volley Request.
2. Use Publisher-Subsriber pattern such as provided by Otto or EventBus.  I'll just demonstrate the magic of Otto.

```
public static class ResponseEvent{
   MyResponse myResponse;
   public ResponseEvent(MyResponse myResponse){
      this.myResponse = myResponse;
   }
}

public void onCreate(){
   BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);// register this activity as subscriber  
}

public void onDestroy(){
   BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
}    
// it is up you where you want to register and unregister depending
// whether you want to digest the response when the activity 
// is on foreground or background as well. 



private Response.Listener<MyResponse> mResponseListener = new Response.Listener<MyResponse>(){
@Override public void onResponse(MyResponse myResponse) {

    // I could get here *after* rotation was initiated

    // do stuff

   BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ResponseEvent(myResponse)); 
//sends this event to previously registered subcsriber. 
//The subscriber method will be active as long the activity 
//hasn't been de-registered. 
//Nothing will happen after unregister has been called.  

}};

//this is the subscriber method that will digest your response
@Subsribe
public void onGotResponse(ResponseEvent event){
   // do your stuff with response here. 
 finish(); 
// notice I moved finish() here so you can be sure 
// it will only be called as long as the activity is still active
}
```